# php date function wrong in 2017-03-22 timestamp

Tags: php, function, date, timestamp

this 1490128200 timestamp is for 2017-03-22 00:00:00

but in output of date function

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s a',1490128200)
```

make this -> 2017-03-22 01:00:00

you can test the 1 second before this timestamp (1490128199), the output becomes to  2017-03-21 23:59:59 pm  **one hour lost  :o**

interesting this problem repeat in each year on this month and date, you can change the year and this problem repeat exactly like this.

have you any solution for solve this?

Comment: Arrays start at 0.  So do timestamps.  I'll let you do the math.

Comment: What timezone are you using?

Comment: `1490128200 + 1 = 1490128201` and not `1521664200`

Comment: `1490128200 - 1 = 1490128199` and not `1521664200`

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tehran');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's date function is working perfectly. [Daylight savings time started in Iran](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/iran/tehran) on March 22 2017 at midnight. So 1 second before midnight the time was  2017-03-21 23:59:59 and 1 second later it became 2017-03-22 01:00:00.